# Dynamically changing the result field value in RestAPI step for Pagination

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm having an issue trying to upload >100 records using the RestAPI step in Spoon, hopefully someone can help please.

The job consists of the following:

1. Transformation 1 is used to first authenticate the connection. It then uses the RestAPI to connect to the system, this specifies:

   1. The initial URL to be used (based on Postman config)
   2. The initial output field name to be used for the data (in my case ‘result’)
   3. The field mappings for the JSON
2. Once transformation 1 connects, the name of the URL is updated to the ‘NextURL’ value in the ‘results’ output
3. Transformation 1 successfully uploads the first 100 records.
4. A check is then done to make sure the ‘NextURL’ is not blank (i.e. there is no more pages of data to upload). If it is blank then the job stops, if not then the job moves to transformation 2
5. Transformation 2 is similar to transformation 1, except there is no need for authentication and it uses the ‘NextURL’ to upload the next set of records. This needs to be able to set the ‘result’ output field to a different value, however this doesn’t happen. The only way to get this to work is to specify a different output name other than ‘result’. If I change the output field name to something else, then the next 100 records are successfully uploaded. However obviously I cannot keep specifying new names for the output field. I need to be able to change the original ‘result’ field data
6. Finally the loop goes back to the check for a blank ‘NextURL’ and again either stops if blank, or loops back to transformation 2 to run again.

The actual loop works fine and if I change the name of the result field in transformation 2, I can upload 200 records, however I need this job to be able to upload a lot more and dynamically change the NextURL and the ‘result’ output field on the RestAPI.

Does anyone know how to change the result field in the output on the RestAPI step?

[Here is a picture of the field I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Hww.png)

I have tried to change this using javascript, however that still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're passing the result rows of Transformation 1 to the parent job and then retrieving them in Transformation 2. Which then has to pass them to the parent, loop back, etc. So your result field will conflict with a field with the same name and will be renamed result_1, result_2, etc.

One way to do that is at the beginning of the Transformation 2 pipeline use a select values to filter our any fields you don't need. That will remove the result field from the previous execution, which allows you to re-use it for the result of the new API call.